# A way to draw a concentric circles' sector in QML?

Tags: qt, qml, shapes

I need to draw something like a target, a bunch of concentric circles split into 12 or so sectors (pizza slices). So the number of "layers" inside the outer circle can change anywhere from 2 to 10, the size of the whole target should remain the same, and the distance between inner circles should be equal (bascially OuterCircleRadius / NumberOfLayers)

So far I came up with a code that basically draws a single segment of a circle, then, by putting a Repeater in the main file I get a full circle, split into 12 sectors, which is what I need. Now I need to find a way to add a number of concentric circles inside the outer one. The problem is that the number of concentric circles is not constant, and is set by user. So the "target" should change when a different number of layers is chosen (for example with a SpinBox). So far my idea is to draw a few additional arcs inside of a single sector so I can keep the Repeater. My code below.

```
// main.qml

import QtQuick 2.12
import QtQuick.Window 2.12
import QtQuick.Layouts
import QtQuick.Controls

Window {
   width: 600
   height: 600
   visible: true
   id: window
   property int sectors: 12
   Rectangle {
       anchors.centerIn: parent
       width: 600
       height: 600
       Repeater {
           model: sectors
           CircleSector {
               anchors.fill: parent
               anchors.margins: 10
               sectors: window.sectors
               sector: index
               fillColor: index == spinBox.value ? "orange" : "aliceblue"
           }
       }
   }
   Frame {
           SpinBox {
               id: spinBox
               Layout.fillWidth: true
               from: 0
               to: sectors - 1
               value: 1
               wrap: true
               stepSize: 1
           }
   }
}

// CircleSector.qml

import QtQuick 2.12
import QtQuick.Shapes 1.12

Shape {
    id: circleSector
    antialiasing: true
    property int sectors: 12
    property int sector: 0
    property real from: sector * (360 / sectors)
    property real to: (sector + 1) * (360 / sectors)
    property real centerX: width / 2
    property real centerY: height / 2
    property alias fillColor: shapePath.fillColor
    property alias strokeColor: shapePath.strokeColor
    property real fromX: centerX + centerX * Math.cos(from * Math.PI / 180)
    property real fromY: centerY + centerY * Math.sin(from * Math.PI / 180)
    property real toX: centerX + centerX * Math.cos(to * Math.PI / 180)
    property real toY: centerY + centerY * Math.sin(to * Math.PI / 180)
    containsMode: Shape.FillContains
    ShapePath{
        id: shapePath
        fillColor: "aliceblue"
        strokeColor: "grey"
        startX: centerX; startY: centerY
        PathLine { x: fromX; y: fromY }
        PathArc{
            radiusX: centerX; radiusY: centerY
            x: toX; y: toY
        }
        PathLine{ x: centerX; y: centerY }
    }
}
```

Comment: @iam_peter [This is a good example](https://ars.els-cdn.com/content/image/1-s2.0-S0920410518309665-gr5.jpg) this one has 4 additional concentric circles inside of the main one, but in my case it's not a constant thing.

Comment: @MilanŠ. Done. Pretty much new to the forum, I'm sorry.

Comment: Do you want the segments to be different objects to be able to color them individually or can those segments just be layered on top?

Comment: Is this gone be a circular coordinate system or all individual objects? Because the segments then could be just lines and the slices just circles.

Comment: @iam_peter No need for them to be individual objects, they can be just layered. I just need a coordinate system.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use this `Canvas` solution. It isn't pretty, but it hopefully does what you want.

```
import QtQuick
import QtQuick.Controls

ApplicationWindow {
    id: root
    title: "Polar Coordinates Canvas"
    width: 640
    height: 480
    visible: true
    color: "white"

    property int numCircles: circlesSpinBox.value
    property int numSegments: segmentsSpinBox.value

    Canvas {
        id: canvas
        anchors.centerIn: parent
        width: 400
        height: canvas.width
        onPaint: {
            var ctx = getContext("2d")

            ctx.fillStyle = 'white'
            ctx.fillRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);

            const centerX = canvas.width / 2
            const centerY = canvas.height / 2
            const radius = canvas.width / 2

            const circleDistance = (canvas.width / 2) / root.numCircles

            for (let i = 1; i <= root.numCircles; ++i) {
                let r = i * circleDistance
                ctx.beginPath()
                ctx.arc(centerX, centerY, r, 0, 2 * Math.PI, false)
                ctx.lineWidth = 1
                ctx.strokeStyle = 'black'
                ctx.stroke()
            }

            if (root.numSegments < 2)
                return

            const segmentAngle = 360 / root.numSegments

            if (root.numSegments % 2 === 0) { // even
                for (let s = 0; s < (root.numSegments / 2); ++s) {
                    let a =  s * segmentAngle

                    ctx.beginPath()

                    let x = centerX + radius * Math.cos(a * (Math.PI / 180))
                    let y = centerY + radius * Math.sin(a * (Math.PI / 180))

                    ctx.moveTo(x, y)

                    x = centerX + radius * Math.cos((a + 180) * (Math.PI / 180))
                    y = centerY + radius * Math.sin((a + 180) * (Math.PI / 180))

                    ctx.lineTo(x, y)
                    ctx.lineWidth = 1
                    ctx.strokeStyle = 'black'
                    ctx.stroke()
                }
            } else { // odd
                for (let s = 0; s < root.numSegments; ++s) {
                    let a =  s * segmentAngle

                    ctx.beginPath()

                    let x = centerX + radius * Math.cos(a * (Math.PI / 180))
                    let y = centerY + radius * Math.sin(a * (Math.PI / 180))

                    ctx.moveTo(x, y)
                    ctx.lineTo(centerX, centerY)
                    ctx.lineWidth = 1
                    ctx.strokeStyle = 'black'
                    ctx.stroke()
                }
            }
        }
    }

    Column {
        SpinBox {
            id: circlesSpinBox
            value: 3
            onValueChanged: canvas.requestPaint()
        }

        SpinBox {
            id: segmentsSpinBox
            value: 7
            onValueChanged: canvas.requestPaint()
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Depending on what you want to do with your polar coordinate system you could use [PolarChartView](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qml-qtcharts-polarchartview.html). With that you can also easily plot data on it.

```
import QtQuick
import QtQuick.Controls
import QtCharts

Window {
    width: 640
    height: 480
    visible: true
    title: qsTr("Hello World")

    PolarChartView {
        anchors.fill: parent
        legend.visible: false
        antialiasing: true

        ValueAxis {
            id: axisAngular
            min: 0
            max: 1
            labelsVisible: false
            lineVisible: false
            tickCount: axisAngularSpinBox.value
        }

        ValueAxis {
            id: axisRadial
            min: 0
            max: 1
            labelsVisible: false
            lineVisible: false
            tickCount: axisRadialSpinBox.value
        }

        SplineSeries {
            id: series
            axisAngular: axisAngular
            axisRadial: axisRadial
            pointsVisible: true
        }
    }

    Column {
        SpinBox {
            id: axisAngularSpinBox
            value: 9
        }

        SpinBox {
            id: axisRadialSpinBox
            value: 10
        }
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: This is great, but is there a way to make the lines not ovelap with the circles?

Comment: I mean not to stick out of the coordinate system.

Comment: You mean that they are sticking out the outer circle? This is dependent on the `PolarChartView` drawing. There might be an option, but I need to have a look. What do you want to do? Do you want to actually draw data on the polar coordinate system? Because if you do so, how do you map the data points on the coordinate system if you don't use premade components?

Comment: I've update my answer. You can use `lineVisible: false` on the `ValueAxis` to hide the tick marks.

Comment: Unfortunately, I just found out that I can't use the QtCharts library, because it requires a QApplication to function, and I have QtGuiApplication. and usage of widgets is prohibited. Guess I'll have to find another way to draw the coordinate system. Do you have any suggestions?